# Any Code Samples for MVVM Closable Tabs Example?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am looking for the code samples or the sample project for the [MSDN: MVVM Design Pattern for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) tutorial. Something similar is fine. I just want to see how I can add/remove tabs dynamically and where commands go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples are available on the [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM) under the [Downloads](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2026) tab.

Answer (score 0):

Sacha Barber did this also in his [Cinch](http://sachabarber.net/?page_id=523) framework, maybe there you find some information too.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the **Writer** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to add/remove tabs when documents are opened or closed. The sample uses MVVM as well.